# How to perform linearity tests on OLS regression [statmodels]

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using the code following to test for linearity, however, somehow statsmodels thinks that my model is not linear. Input:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import linear_reset


x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

regression = sm.OLS(y, x).fit_regularized()
linear_reset(regression, power = 2, test_type = "fitted")
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: result must come from a linear regression model
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`linear_reset` needs a RegressionResults object as first argument, while the object returned in line
`regression = sm.OLS(y, x).fit_regularized()`
by the `fit_regularized()` method is a `RegularizedResultsWrapper`.

If you want to use the `linear_reset` test you should use an unregularized OLS model by calling the `.fit()` method, this way the returned object is a `RegressionResultsWrapper` and can be passed to `linear_reset`.

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import linear_reset


x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

regression = sm.OLS(y, x)
result = regression.fit()

linear_reset(result, power = 2, test_type = "fitted")
```

This error makes sense, because one is trying to test the non-linearity of a regularized model, while the function assumes an un-regularized model.

In particular, the `linear_reset` test assumes that the given model is a un-regularized OLS and tries to prove the non-linearity of the relationship between x and y.
If one were to apply this test to a regularized model, the above assumption won't hold anymore and the test result is meaningless; for example it can report a missing non-linearity, while this can be caused by the regularization factor which brings the values of the parameters closer to 0.

Comment: But why it makes no sense to test for linearity, if regularised linear regression has to be linear?

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully the reasoning makes more sense now.